# How to select only the last entry in my table?

Tags: sql, database, date, join, select

I have the tables `Matieres` and `Resultats`

```
 ___ Matieres ___            ___ Resultats ___
    id (int auto increment)      ID (int auto_increment)
    Nom (varchar)            TIME_OF_INSERTION (datetime current_timestamp)
    Categorie (varchar)          ID_USER (int)
    Active (boolean)             ID_MATIERE (int)
                                 RESULTAT (int)
```

And i have this request:

`SELECT * FROM Matieres LEFT JOIN Resultats ON Matieres.id = Resultats.ID_MATIERE AND Resultats.ID_USER = :userid WHERE Active = TRUE AND ID_Formation = :formation)`

The problem is that it returns me every resultats the user inserted in the table Resultats, for each Matieres. When i just want the last one inserted for each `Matieres.Nom` ... :/

I tried with `GROUP BY TIME_OF_INSERTION`  but it won't work :(

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Matieres m LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT r.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_Matiere, id_user ORDER BY time_of_insertions DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Resultats r
      WHERE r.ID_USER = :userid 
     ) r
     ON m.id = r.ID_MATIERE AND
        seqnum = 1
WHERE Active = TRUE AND ID_Formation = :formation;
```

Comment: Your SQL request works perfectly ! Problem solved ! 1000 times thx to you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

try adding `index 1` at the end of the query for the last and only 1 record